# List extraction with multiple lines

Tags: python-3.x

I have long string of variables from list extraction. How can I conform PEP 8 and do break line

```
message_id, message_content_type, message_content, message_caption, message_likes_count, message_attachments = message
```

Must looks like

```
message_id, message_content_type, message_content, message_caption, 
message_likes_count, message_attachments = message
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to go about this? Why is it a list in the first place? A more rigid structure would make more sense if you're storing data positionally like this.

Comment: Why "Must looks like"? And what does that even mean, given that it *can't* because that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy it into the [Black Playground](https://black.now.sh), it produces this:

```
(
    message_id,
    message_content_type,
    message_content,
    message_caption,
    message_likes_count,
    message_attachments,
) = message
```

I usually like to use few lines, but I gotta say this happens to look *very* readable.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` operator can be used to force-break a line:

```
message_id, message_content_type, message_content, message_caption, \
message_likes_count, message_attachments = message
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this way:

```
(message_id, message_content_type, message_content, message_caption, 
message_likes_count, message_attachments) = message  # Explicity brackets helps
```